# Tensorflow: next_batch function of np array

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have train data as

```
xTrain = numpy.asarray([100, 1, 5, 6 ...])
yTrain = numpy.asarray([200, 2, 10, 12 ...])
```

How to define next_batch(size) method to get  size number of random elements from the train data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as your `next batch` function:

```
def batch_data(source, target, batch_size):

   # Shuffle data
   shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(target)))
   source = source[shuffle_indices]
   target = target[shuffle_indices]

   for batch_i in range(0, len(source)//batch_size):
      start_i = batch_i * batch_size
      source_batch = source[start_i:start_i + batch_size]
      target_batch = target[start_i:start_i + batch_size]

      yield np.array(source_batch), np.array(target_batch)
```

Comment: ValueError: too many values to unpack
 When I gave batch_size greater than size if source.

Comment: you want batch_size > source size?. why? then its no longer a `batch`. Can you edit your question of what functionality you actually  want?