# Reading numpy matrix in batches in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to run some regression models on GPU. While I get a very low GPU utilization upto 20%. After going through the code,

```
 for i in range(epochs):
    rand_index = np.random.choice(args.train_pr,
        size=args.batch_size)
    rand_x = X_train[rand_index]
    rand_y = Y_train[rand_index]
```

I use these three lines for selecting a random batch for each iteration. So, I wanted to ask when the training is going on, can I ready up one more batch for the next iteration?

I am working on a regression problem and not a classification problem. I have already seen threading in Tensorflow but found the examples only for images and there's no example for a big matrix of size 100000X1000 which is used for training.

Comment: Its a duplicate to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110098/tensorflow-next-batch-function-of-np-array/45110647#45110647

Answer (score 3):

You have a large numpy array that lies on the host memory. You want to be able to process it in parallel on the CPU and send batches to the device.

Since TF 1.4, the best way to do it is to use `tf.data.Dataset`, and particularly `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`. However, as [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays) points out, you should probably *not* provide your numpy arrays as arguments to this function, because it will end up being copied to device memory. What you should do instead is to use placeholders. The example given in the doc is pretty self-explanatory:

```
features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(features.dtype, features.shape)
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(labels.dtype, labels.shape)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
# [Other transformations on `dataset`...]
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: features,
                                          labels_placeholder: labels})
```

Further preprocessing or data augmentation can be applied to the slices using the `.map` method. To make sure that those operations happen concurrently, make sure to use tensorflow operations only and avoid wrapping python operations with `tf.py_func`.

Comment: Using this method, can I make changes to x and y at certain step? Let's say I am using K- cross validation and I need to swap some samples of x with some other samples in between after a certain step. Is it possible to do so? Thanks!

Comment: @Deepak Yes! I edited my question to mark the place where preprocessing should happen.

Comment: I believe there's some mistake in the sccript since for tf.py_func, tf.placeholder should be the input rather than a Numpy array. Can you refer this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func

Comment: Did you get an error while running the script? Please tell me more. It works fine by me.

Comment: Hey, I get the following error when I run it. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ymLyaURGRiDGH6jDa3T0qv1VA0BvczgDjGPZ1PZNDfY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for generators. You can set up a generator function to yield slices of your `numpy` matrices one chunk at a time. If you use a package like `Keras`, you can supply the generator directly to the `train_on_batch` function. If you prefer to use `Tensorflow` directly, you can use:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
batch_gen = generator(data)
batch = batch_gen.next()
sess.run([optimizer, loss, ...], feed_dict = {X: batch[0], y: batch[1]})
```

Note: I am using placeholders for the optimizer and loss, you have to replace with your definitions. Note that your generator should yield a **(x, y)** tuple. If you are unfamiliar with generator expressions, there are many examples online, but here is a simple example from the `Keras` documentation that shows how you can read in `numpy` matrices from a file in batches:

```
def generate_arrays_from_file(path):
    while 1:
        f = open(path)
        for line in f:
            x, y = process_line(line)
            yield (x, y)
        f.close()
```

But also more fundamentally, a low GPU-usage is not really indicative of any problem loading batches, but rather that your batch size might be too small.