# How to exchange 'mnist.train.next_batch' to 'tf.train.batch' in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

tensorflow 1.2

I started learning tensorflow using mnist dataset in tf.

And I changed dataset. 
I faced this problem that exchanging 'batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)' to 'batch_xs, batch_ys = tf.train.batch([X, Y], batch_size = batch_size)'.

I want to know how to apply minibatch in tensorflow.

## Error Message

TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.

```
train_data.shape, train_labels.shape # numpy
# ((10000, 20, 20, 3), (10000, 2))


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10000, 20, 20, 3])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10000, 10])

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4, 4, 3, 32], stddev=0.01))

L1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X, W1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding = 'SAME')
L1 = tf.nn.relu(L1)
L1 = tf.nn.max_pool(L1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
L1 = tf.reshape(L1, [-1, 10 * 10 * 32])

W2 = tf.get_variable('W2', shape=[10 * 10 * 32, 10], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))

hypothesis = tf.matmul(L1, W2) + b

learning_rate = 0.001
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=hypothesis, labels = Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# hyper parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 5
batch_size = 100

for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    avg_cost = 0
    total_batch = int(10000 / batch_size)
    for i in range(total_batch):
        # batch_xs, batch_ys = tf.train.batch([X, Y], batch_size)
        batch_xs, batch_ys = tf.train.batch([X, Y], batch_size = batch_size)
        feed_dict = {X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys}
        c, _, = sess.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict = feed_dict)
        avg_cost += c / total_batch
    print('Epoch: ', '%04d' % (epoch + 1), 'cost: ', '{:.9f}'.format(avg_cost))



TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.
```

Comment: The error is because you are feeding a tensor to `feed_dict`. Change your - feed_dict={X:train_data_batch, Y: train_label_batch}.  Both train_data_batch and train_label_batch are numpy array's

Comment: @vijaym Can you tell me how to do batch(numpy array), please?  
I'm beginner about tensorflow.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110098/tensorflow-next-batch-function-of-np-array/45110647?noredirect=1#comment77193477_45110647

Answer (score 0):

`batch_xs, batch_ys = tf.train.batch([X, Y], batch_size = batch_size)` This statement is still in building graph stage. Nothing would happen unless you call `sess.run(...)` on them.

You can go to tensorflow doc and tutorial for applying minibatch.

Comment: Can you upload tf document url about this, please?

Comment: I cannot found about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add any tensorflow API out of the graph like `batch_xs, batch_ys = tf.train.batch([X, Y], batch_size = batch_size)` you are doing in my code.

It makes the batch_xs and batch_ys as tensor. The thing you can do, is to write the `batch_xs, batch_ys = tf.train.batch([X, Y], batch_size = batch_size)` in the graph, evaluate batch_xs and batch_ys, and then feed that in the process.